# Where to get resources and demonstration on second order SQL injection?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I've been trawling around in the internet for a demo on second order SQLi but I still haven't found one yet. Many sites don't really give a thorough explanation on how it works.
I need to present a short demonstration and I've been practicing using Mutillidae. Can anybody lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

A Google search for 'second order sql injection' comes up with a number of more or less relevant explanations of what Second Order SQL Injection is, with differing degrees of detail (as you say).

The basic idea is that the database stores some text from the user that is later incorporated into an SQL statement — but the text is insufficiently sanitized before reuse.

Think of an application which allows a user to create user-defined queries against a database.  A simple example might be a bug tracking system.  Some of the user-defined query attributes might be simple conditions such as 'bug status is "closed"'.  This might be coded by looking at the stored query definition:

```
CREATE TABLE UserDefinedQuery
(
    ...user info...,
    bug_status    VARCHAR(20),
    ...other info...
);

SELECT ..., bug_status, ...
  INTO ..., hv_bug_status, ...
  FROM UserDefinedQuery
 WHERE bug_status IS NOT NULL
   AND ...other criteria...
```

where `hv_bug_status` is a host variable (PHP, C, whatever language you're using) holding the bug status criterion.

If this value is `= 'closed'`, then the resulting SQL might contain:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Bugs
 WHERE status = 'closed'
   AND ...other criteria...
```

Now suppose that when the user defined their query, they wrote instead:

```
= 'open' or 1=1
```

This means that the generated query now looks like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Bugs
 WHERE status = 'open' or 1=1
   AND ...other criteria...
```

The presence of the `OR` changes the meaning of the query dramatically and will show all sorts of other records that were not the ones that the user was intended to see.  This is a bug in the bug querying application.  If this modification means that CustomerX can see bugs reported by other customers CustomerY and CustomerZ that they are not supposed to see, then CustomerX has managed to create a second order SQL injection attack.  (If the injection simply means that they get to see more records than they should, including ones that aren't relevant to them, then they've simply created a buggy query.)

Clearly, in a VARCHAR(20) field, your options for injecting lethal SQL are limited simply because SQL is a verbose language.  But ['little Bobby Tables'](http://xkcd.com/327) could strike if the criteria are stored in a longer field.

```
='';DELETE Bugs;--
```

(Using a non-standard contraction for the DELETE statement; that squeaks in at 18 characters.)

How can you avoid this?  Don't allow the user to write raw SQL fragments that you include in the generated SQL.  Treat the value in UserDefinedQuery.Bug_Status as a space/comma separated list of string values, and build the query accordingly:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Bugs
 WHERE status IN ('=', '''open''', 'or', '1=1')
   AND ...other criteria...
```

The query may not be useful, but it doesn't get its structure altered by the data in the UserDefinedQuery table.